# How to filter GridView data by eg. second or tenth character, DevExpress Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress, filtering

I need to add custom filter which will filter data in the column by eg second character.

Example:
*Values in column: ABCD, DEFG, ABAB, DAAC.*
*Filter: first letter any, second = 'B'*
*After filtering I want to see only ABCD & ABAB.*

DevExpress allows to create custom filters but I can't see something like this.
 
Maybe someone had a similar problem in the past?

Answer (score 2):

Use [ActiveFilterString](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.ActiveFilterString.property/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.ActiveFilter.property) property.

```
 mygridview.ActiveFilterString = "[MyColumn] LIKE '_B%'";
```

This says: start with any letter, the second one must be a B, follwerd by any string.

[More](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/2567/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Filter-and-Search/Advanced-Filter-and-Search-Concepts) about filtering.